# SQL where between date clause referencing multiple date ranges

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two SQL customer tables I am trying to merge.

```
CustomerDate:
Column 1: customerkey int
Column 2: RecentPurchase smalldatetime- the date of their most recent purchase
Column 3: PriorYear smalldatetime - the RecentPurchase date minus a year

CustomerTrans:
Column 1: Transactionkey int
Column 2: customerkey int
Column 3: TransactionDate smalldatetime- Date of Transaction
Column 4: Amount - Total Amount Spent
```

I would like to get the total amount spent by a customer between their most RecentPurchase and the PriorYear Date. I have tried the below query but it is not returning any results.

```
select t.customerkey, 
       sum(t.amount)
from customertrans t
inner join customerdate d on t.customerkey = d.customerkey
where  TransactionDate between RecentPurchase and PriorYear
group by t.customerkey
```

How do I run the query so that each customers TransactionDate is determined by the dates in the CustomerDate table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you just want :

```
where TransactionDate between PriorYear and RecentPurchase
```

Instead of :

```
where TransactionDate between RecentPurchase and PriorYear
```

Comment: Yep, super embarrassed.  So Easy.  Thanks GMB!